# /../usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgo/cgo.go:34:8: could not import C (cgo preprocessing failed) (typecheck)

Tags: go, linter, golangci-lint

Note:

- current version of Go - 1.17.13
- current version of golangci-lint - 1.45.2

I am getting the same error `could not import C (cgo preprocessing failed) (typecheck) no matter which version of golangci-lint I use while I am running golangci-lint.

I have seen this issue on Github: https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/1176 where it is told to add header files (like `net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h` and `net-snmp/mib_api.h`)  to  `/usr/local/include.`

Personally, I found this kinda files in `/usr/include` directory, and I copied all files with `.h` extension to `/usr/local/include.`

Plus, I also installed  `libsnmp-dev` as it is said in the link above.

But, I got the same error again...

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: Don't just copy header files around - that's never the right answer here.

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. After installing gcc, everything worked. Btw, thanks for your comment @torek

Comment: Interesting that Go reported the missing compiler in this bizarre way. That can probably be improved. (I had no idea what the actual problem was!)

Comment: @Komron how to install gcc any command

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but the solution was damn easy for this issue which took my 2 days.

What I did was to change `import "C"` to `import ( "C" )` in `/usr/local/go/src/runtime/cgo/cgo.go` file, and installing gcc.

That's it, guys :)

P.S: you are welcome to share your own answers as well because personally I didn't understand my own solution

Comment: The import statement is equivalent, and you do not need to edit the runtime source. Installing gcc was what you were missing. You can’t use cgo without a C compiler.

Comment: @JimB you are right. Actually, I reinstalled my OS ubuntu, but on SSD this time. However, in my previous OS (it's totally the same as the previous one), I wasn't asked to install gcc to use linter.

Comment: how to install gcc?